# Bypass sitemap.xml from redirect rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Our application is deployed on JBOSS. We have enabled AJP module on Apache. We have written redirect rules. Now, we are planning to keep sitemap.xml in /var/www/mysite folder. So that when search engine BOT accesses www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml, the sitemap.xml from /var/www/mysite folder should be served. All other requests should be redirected to JBOSS via AJP.

Configuration in apache.conf

```
ProxyPass /mysite  ajp://1.0.0.0:8009/mysite
ProxyPassReverse /mysite  ajp://1.0.0.0:8080/mysite
```

Configuration in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|css)(.*) /$1$2
RewriteRule / /mysite
```

Solution tried but did not worked :(
Solution 1

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml [QSA,L]
```

Solution 2

```
ProxyRequests off 
ProxyPass /sitemap.xml !
```

Can someone help me in writing rule which will serve sitemap.xml from var/www/mysite folder? Today, when I type www.example.com/sitemap.xml, Apache redirects to example.com/mysite

Comment: Any suggestions? Even pointers/readings suggestion appreciated. I will deep dive into the suggested topics

Answer (score 0):

Got solution using

RewriteRule /?sitemap.xml %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitemap.xml [L]

This solution I got from question [mod-rewrite rule for sitemap.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135955/mod-rewrite-rule-for-sitemap-xml)

So up vote goes to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and not to me.